# Regular expression not matching as I expect

Tags: regex, perl, bash, unix

I have the following string: `connect_2014-06-03.csv` and the following regex: `(\S+)[_-]`.

What I want to do is extract only the first word, i.e. `connect` from the string, but for some reason the regex matches `connect_2014-06-`. I have tried to make it non greedy by doing `(\S+)[_-]?` But that does not seem to work.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `+` that is greedy, not the overall regex. You need to modify the `\S+` inside your capture group to not be as greedy.

```
(\S+?)[_-]
```

Also see this [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yW0iI9).

Maybe it makes sense not to use *any non-whitespace character*, but instead just use `([a-z]+)_`? Remember, dash and underscore are also non-whitespace.

Comment: Also remember that underscore is in `\w`

Answer (score 1):

You can use BASH string manipulation instead of regex:

```
s='connect_2014-06-03.csv'
echo "${s%%_*}"
connect
```

For using regex you can use:

```
[[ "$s" =~ ^([^_]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
connect
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy solutions to this.

You can explicitly state that you want non-greedy by adding a `?` to your quantifier.

```
(\S+?)[_-]
```

Or you can make your character class limit itself:

```
([^_-\s]*)
```